# Singleton and other parameterized constructors

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I have just made my class singleton by following simple code:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance=null;

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance==null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I also want to be able to set some properties using a constructor. However, I am little worried since this is my first time with singleton. I have following questions:

1. How can I have other parameterized constructor and also make sure that when a client application uses my class they get singleton.
2. Would it be a bad idea to have multiple constructor with singleton class?
3. What are there are multiple calls to the new "parameterized constructor" with different values?

Comment: An external constructor defeats the entire idea of a singleton. You cannot instance the singleton yourself, that's what keeps it *single*.

Comment: Ok so it means that singleton is a good for only stateless object, like serviecs?

Comment: Singletons can have a state, it's just shared among all instances and the amount of instances is always equal to 1. Singletons will often be stateless, but that's mainly because it makes sense and not necessarily a requirement.

Comment: Not a good idea, a setup or initialise method on the Singleton instance, or just discrete properties would be better. PS you might want to google for a better implementation, before you do anything serious.

Comment: What happens on concurrent accesses to the property? Two instances could be created and each access could be getting different instances.

Comment: What problem are you solving with a Singleton? Are you suffering from [patternitis](http://dreamaranis.com/blog/design-patterns-and-%E2%80%98patternitis%E2%80%99)?

Comment: I think I got your point everyone. If I want different interlaces to hold different values for each property then singleton is the last thing I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons are stateless, should not have any state in it. By looking at your problem you are looking for a Factory Pattern which can be created by Singleton. I think this link will help you [factory-method-and-singleton-patterns](http://designpatternsinjava.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/factory-method-and-singleton-patterns/)